# How to have different colors of radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZjOWj What i want is when user is on first radio button it need to be blue and when he is on second it need to be green. Any suggestion?

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  color: #292321;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="radio01" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio01"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>

<div>
 <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
 <label for="radio02"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you need the radiobuttons to be blue and green respectively? What is the antecedent of 'it' in your second sentence?

Comment: first radio button when is checked it need to be blue when i checked second radio button it need to be green and then first will be "blank" ofc

Comment: So 'it' refers to the radiobutton that is clicked, not to some other external div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now in your CSS, you're only checking whether or not any radiobutton is checked, and painting it blue. You need to create an option so that you can differ between radiobuttons (to give them different colours for instance).

Classes are great for this, they're pretty much meant for this functionality.
Adapt your HTML so that it looks like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" class="blue" id="radio01" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio01"><span></span>Radio Button 1</label>
</div>

<div>
 <input type="radio" id="radio02" class="green" name="radio" />
 <label for="radio02"><span></span>Radio Button 2</label>
</div>
```

Notice how the radiobuttons now differ in their class attributes (so now you can access  them seperately.

Adapt your CSS like this:

```
input[type="radio"].green:checked + label span{
     background-color:green;
     border:1px solid blue;
}

input[type="radio"].blue:checked + label span{
     background-color:blue;
     border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Now your CSS will paint radiobuttons that have their class set to blue, blue, and the ones classed as green, green.

Comment: thats it ...tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just target the second div by adding a class or using `nth-child` selector etc. Then apply a different color for the circle.

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZRpZz?editors=1100)**

```
div:nth-child(2) input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
  background: green;
}
```